# Does Windows 7/8 have universal API to control music player working any music player?

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-8, windows-7, audio-player

I want to query status, pause/resume music players from my application.

Is there a universal API for this in Windows 7/8, or I need to write custom code for each player like it was in the old times?

Answer (score 2):

There is no universal API at the level of the operating system that works to control any and all music players. How would such a thing even work? Each music player is different and has different capabilities, but the API can't possibly reflect that. And what about additional features, above and beyond what is supported by the API in that particular version of Windows?

There is an API for the Windows Media Player, but the user might be using something else. Or they might be using multiple media player applications at the same time. Which one would you be controlling?

Comment: Worth pointing out the `VK_MEDIA_*` virtual key codes (i.e. what gets sent on a keyboard with play/stop/track function keys) although of course support for these need to have been written into the player in question.

Comment: For what it's worth, this does exist in Linux/*BSD, see: http://specifications.freedesktop.org/mpris-spec/latest/
It does only allow a specified set of features, but it does support controlling multiple applications, etc.